# Configuring ADFS 3.0 / SAML 2.0 to work with Spring Security for SSO integration

Tags: spring-security, adfs, spring-saml

I followed chapter 12.0 instructions about using spring with adfs as IdP from here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf

But I have an exception when I test the SSO :

```
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: NameID element must be present as part of the Subject in the Response message, please enable it in the IDP configuration
```

I added the rule NameID as described in the document.
We use ADFS 3.0 on a server and Tomcat on another Linux server, but I don't think it has an impact on this...
I can't find a way to resolve it, is someone (@vschafer ?) has a suggestion ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution : I had to set Rule Type as "Pass through or filter an incoming claim" because our ADFS server uses others claim providers.

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807060(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I wouldn't have figured this out without trying to reproduce it. I'll put a mention to the manual.